# bad symbolic reference. A signature in WebUI.class refers to term eclipse in package org which is not available

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am building my spark environment, refering to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#spark-tests-in-maven.  But when i use this command: "mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.3 -DskipTests -Phive -Phive-thriftserver clean package", I met some errors.

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in WebUI.class refers to term eclipse
[error] in package org which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling WebUI.class.
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in WebUI.class refers to term jetty
[error] in value org.eclipse which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling WebUI.class.
[error]
[error]      while compiling: /download_wlh/spark-1.6.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala
[error]         during phase: erasure
[error]      library version: version 2.10.5 
[error]     compiler version: version 2.10.5
```

There is somebody ask a question which is similar to this. Refering to [strange error message: bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to term apache in package org which is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336834/strange-error-message-bad-symbolic-reference-a-signature-in-package-class-refe)

But there are no solutions mentioned.

Comment: in which phase do you get these errors? It would also be helpful if you cod provide the WebUI signature that is refereed and the place where it is called.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem as you trying to make a Spark distribution with Hadoop 2.4 using Java 8 and Scala 2.11.

My original attempt was: `./make-distribution.sh --name hadoop-2.4-custom --tgz -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.11`

This produced the error described in [Spark SQL 1.5 build failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656734/spark-sql-1-5-build-failure)

Following the advice from that post, I ran `./dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh` and then omitted the `-Dscala-2.11` as one of the comments suggested. This yielded your exact error. When I added the scala flag back in, the build passed. In summary, I fixed all my problems with:

`./dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh
./make-distribution.sh --name hadoop-2.4-custom --tgz -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.11`

Comment: That worked for me. Here is the command I used `build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.5 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package`